# ¿Cómo hacer un gráfico de círculos superpuestos?

Tags: r, rstudio

Podrian ayudarme por favor con lo siguiente:

Necesito hacer tres gráficos cada uno con una variable biológica distinta, no son datos numéricos, solo tienen un poco información escrita dentro; quiero que los tres círculos estén superpuestos para colocar en el centro el factor que tienen en común.

Estoy usando ggplot2 pero nunca he hecho un gráfico de este tipo en R

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Tu pregunta así como está es demasiado amplia, por lo que eventualmente terminará cerrada, te sugiero que agregues un ejemplo de los datos de cada uno de los conjuntos para que te podamos ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si te he entendido bien, prueba con esto y me dices:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

x0 <- 0
y0 <- 0

r1 <- 1
r2 <- 2
r3 <- 3

grafico <- ggplot()+
  geom_circle(mapping = aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r3),
              fill = "red")+
  geom_circle(mapping = aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r2),
              fill = "blue")+
  geom_circle(mapping = aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r1),
             fill = "green")+
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 2.5, label = "Texto 3"))+
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 1.5, label = "Texto 2"))+
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = "Texto 1"))+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1,
              xlim = c(-3.5,3.5),
              ylim = c(-3.5,3.5))

print(grafico)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]